# Merge one folder with sources into another

Tags: linux, merge, diff

No SCM involved!

Assume I have two folders with sources which are the same (same structure, same files). Then I change sources in one folder and want to merge those changes into another folder. How can I achive that?

Usually I use p4merge to merge single files.

I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of comparison tools which supports compare directories.

Beyond Compare, Meld, Krusader, ... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)